# How to open inspect element in Firefox browser

Tags: angular, firefox, inspector

I am working on Angular project with Firefox browser. I want to open Inspect element in order to check API's data and debugging Typescript code.

I have tried *Ctrl + Shift + C*, *Right Click* but not getting this option.

How can I open Inspect Element?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + C

Comment: Press `F12` and in the left corner the `Inspect Element` button.

Comment: @d-h-e - Nothing happening when pressing Ctrl + Shift + C

Answer (score 1):

Steps to get the Inspector in Firefox:

1. Click on the web page.
2. Context Menu (Right click) -> Inspect Element(Q)
3. Ctrl+Shift+C-(Select Tool) .
4. Select any element to modify and see the changes.

Comment: When I am Right clicking on web page not getting inspect element option

Comment: Please check if the Firefox browser version is 10 or above.Since the inspector was introduced in Version 10.Check using Firefox->Help->About Firefox